# JavaScript code analysis in VS2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

It is possible to enable a code editor helpers for .js files in Visual Studio 2010.

I am tasked to alter the existing JavaSript files, and I am having a hard time to even getting around the written codes, since VS editor treats JS as text. I think Notepad++ would do a better job in this case.

Consider a simple example in the image below:

[image: Bad intellisense for JS in VS]

When an opening braces are selected, the closing ones should also be highlighted so see the boundaries of the function.

The question is: Is there an extension, or some other add-in to VS to enable comfort javascript editing?

Comment: ReSharper 6 may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed) looks good